# Hash Encryption Purpose

Tags: hash

My roommate and I had a conversation about hashing and encryption and their purpose in blockchain etc. We were curious as to why we would encrypt something that cannot be decrypted. It seems pointless since we cannot decrypt some information, it must mean we don't need it, thus leading to the question of why would we store it. Because wouldn't it be a waste of storage? Does anyone know why?

My question in short is, why would we encrypt something we cannot decrypt?

Comment: One-way encrypted data is useful whenever entities need to prove to each other that they share the same key without providing the key itself.  Both agree to encrypt the same data with their key and compare the results. A concrete example: for a person to prove they know the same password provided to a system in an earlier session, the system need store only the encrypted password.  (The sessions are the entities.)

Comment: You have mistakenly called hashing 'encryption', and now want to know what good it is if you can't decrypt it? Anyway, a tutorial on crypto hashes is probably off-topic here but there's always [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).